# problem in using rosserial/arduino in groovy

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello every one.
I want to use Arduino uno to just send a helloworld to ros. I am using groovy.
from the and follow the instruction here that is in rosserial tutorials

I followed ROSBUILD, after "rosmake rosserial_arduino" I can not run "roscd rosserial_arduino/libraries" because this location does not exist. after that I found the rosserial_arduino in /opt/ros/groovy/share/ and in this folder I found ros_lib. So I added ros_lib to my arduino IDE libraries.

I want to write codes in my IDE, just after adding #include<ros.h> I see this error:

In file included from sketch_sep05a.ino:1:
/home/mohammad/Desktop/Arduino/arduino-1.5.3/libraries/ros_lib/ros.h:38:29: error: ros/node_handle.h: No such file or directory
In file included from sketch_sep05a.ino:1:
/home/mohammad/Desktop/Arduino/arduino-1.5.3/libraries/ros_lib/ros.h:49: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token

I think that header files like ros.h have problems. what should I do?
What is the best way to use rosserial and rosserial_arduino in groovy?
thanks a lot!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76447/problem-in-using-rosserial/arduino-in-groovy/) by [narenji](https://answers.ros.org/users/6112/narenji/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-09-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you checked out the groovy-devel branch from the rosserial github project, then you need to build with catkin, not rosmake. You will also likely have to do the "install" step, because rosserial_arduino actually gets a number of it's roslib files from rosserial_client during the install step.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem because they say in the ROS Wiki to copy the ros_lib to Sketchbook folder.

when i copied the ros_lib to **/usr/share/arduino/libraries/**

it worked fine.

Now i can compile any code with ros.h or any other RSO code

---

Originally posted by [Neo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2306/neo/) with karma: 23 on 2013-09-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1